# httpconfig is not able to combine url params with the request url

Tags: angularjs, typescript

My code is as shown below:

RestaurentInfoController.ts

```
module App.Controller {
    import Services = Core.Services;
    import Shared = Core.Shared;

    export class RestaurentInfoController extends BaseController {

        public userName: any;
        public password: any;
        public validUserName: boolean = false;
        public validPassword: boolean = false;
        public restaurentName: any = [];
        public checkBox: any;
        public restaurent: any;
        public foodTruckList: any = [];
        public foodCategories: any = [];
        public drinkCategories: any = [];

        static $inject: Array<string> = ['baseAppService', 'userAuthorizationService', 'storageService', 'eventService',];

        constructor(
            appService: Services.BaseAppService
            , public userAuthorizationService: Services.UserAuthorizationService,
            public storageService: Services.StorageService,
            public eventService: Services.AppEventBusService) {
            super(appService);
            this.getRestaurentList();
        }
        routeTo(view) {
            this.appService.routerService.routeToPage(view);
        }

        getRestaurentList = (): void => {
            this.appService.networkService.get<any>(this.appService.appConstant.appUrls.getFoodTruckName).then((response) => {
                this.foodTruckList = response.data;
            },
                (error) => { });
        }

        changeStatus = (): void => {
            if (this.checkBox === '1') {
                this.getFoodCategories();
            }
            else if (this.checkBox === '2') {
                this.getDrinkCategories();
            }
        }

        getFoodCategories = (): void => {
            console.log("rest " + this.restaurent);
            var data = {
                _id: 'this.restaurent._id'
            }
            this.appService.networkService.get<any>(this.appService.appConstant.appUrls.getFoodCategories,data).then((response) => {
                this.foodCategories = response.data;
                console.log('popuar Items Loaded', this.foodCategories);
            },
                (error) => { });
        }

        getDrinkCategories = (): void => {
            var data = {
                _id: this.restaurent._id
            }
            this.appService.networkService.get<any>(this.appService.appConstant.appUrls.getFoodTruckName, data).then((response) => {
                this.foodTruckList = response.data;
                console.log('popuar Items Loaded', this.foodTruckList);
            },
                (error) => { });
        }
    }

}
```

NetworkService.ts

```
/// <reference path="../../../typings/app.d.ts" />
/// <reference path="../../../typings/tsd.d.ts" />


module Core.Services {

    export class NetworkService {
        static $inject: Array<string> = ['$http', '$log', '$q', 'appConstant', 'storageService'];

        constructor(public $http: ng.IHttpService, public $log: ng.ILogService, public $q: ng.IQService,
            public appConstant: Shared.AppConstants, public storageService: Services.StorageService) { }

        private onError(error: any): void {
            // generic handling for all error, including authorization realted stuff
            this.$log.error(error);
        }

        private getConfig(url: string, config?: ng.IRequestShortcutConfig): ng.IRequestConfig {
            var httpConfig = <ng.IRequestConfig>{};
            if (config != null) {
                angular.extend(httpConfig, config);
            }

            var token = this.storageService.getItem(this.appConstant.keys.token, false);
            if (token != null) {

                var tokenHeader = {
                    'Authorization': "Bearer " + token
                };

                var currentHeaders = httpConfig.headers;
                if (currentHeaders) {
                    httpConfig.headers = angular.extend(currentHeaders, tokenHeader);

                } else {
                    httpConfig.headers = tokenHeader;
                }
            }

            httpConfig.url = url;
            return httpConfig;
        }

        private getOrDelete<T>(url: string, methodType: string, config?: ng.IRequestShortcutConfig): ng.IPromise<T> {

            var httpConfig = this.getConfig(url, config);
            httpConfig.method = methodType;
            return this.getResponse<T>(httpConfig);
        }

        private getResponse<T>(config: ng.IRequestConfig): ng.IPromise<T> {
            var deferred = this.$q.defer();

            config.headers
            this.$http(config).success(
                (result: any) => {
                    deferred.resolve(result);
                }).error((error, errorCode) => {
                    this.onError(error);
                    deferred.reject(new Core.Models.HttpError(error, errorCode));
                });


            return deferred.promise;
        }


        get<T>(url: string, data?: any, config?: ng.IRequestShortcutConfig): ng.IPromise<T> {

            var httpConfig = this.getConfig(url, config);
            httpConfig.method = "GET";
            if (data) {
                httpConfig.params = data;
            }
            return this.getResponse(httpConfig);
        }


        delete<T>(url: string, data?: any, config?: ng.IRequestShortcutConfig): ng.IPromise<T> {

            var httpConfig = this.getConfig(url, config);
            httpConfig.method = "DELETE";
            if (data) {
                httpConfig.params = data;
            }
            return this.getResponse(httpConfig);
        }


        post<T>(url: string, data: any, config?: ng.IRequestShortcutConfig): ng.IPromise<T> {

            var httpConfig = this.getConfig(url, config);
            httpConfig.method = "POST";
            httpConfig.data = jQuery.param(data);
            httpConfig.headers = {
                'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
            };
            return this.getResponse<T>(httpConfig);
        }

        put<T>(url: string, data: any, config?: ng.IRequestShortcutConfig): ng.IPromise<T> {

            var httpConfig = this.getConfig(url, config);
            httpConfig.method = "PUT";
            httpConfig.data = data;
            return this.getResponse<T>(httpConfig);
        }

        patch<T>(url: string, data: any, config?: ng.IRequestShortcutConfig): ng.IPromise<T> {

            var httpConfig = this.getConfig(url, config);
            httpConfig.method = "PATCH";
            httpConfig.data = data;
            return this.getResponse<T>(httpConfig);
        }
    }
}
```

Now what happens here is for `getFoodCategories()`, I am getting the end urls as 
`http://myAPi.com/items/categories?_id=this.restaurent._id`. But i want url like this `http://myAPi.com/items/categories/this.restaurent._id`.Is there anything missing in my `NetworkService.ts` file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are passing the `data` as query string. Instead of passing it as a query string you can form it using [template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals). Notice that `data` is not passed as a parameter.

```
this.appService.networkService.get<any>(`${this.appService.appConstant.appUrls.getFoodCategories}/${this.restaurent._id}`)
    .then((response) => {        
    },
    (error) => { });
}
```